# Symfony wont save some new fields in an entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, entity

I had an entity and it worked fine, after test i added new field to it, now all fields will save but new!!
this is new field in my entity:

```
/**
 * @var string
 */
private $LocationName;
```

should i use a command to reload the entities from cache or something like this?

Comment: Did you add LocationName to your orm mapping file?  Did you run app/console doctrine:schema:update to update the database table?

Comment: Thank you, i have forgot to add this in mapping file, thanks alot